# Output graphics code Error

Tags: graphics, formatting

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100,labelsep=3pt}

\def\f[#1,#2]{2*2^(-2.5*(#1-#2)^2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,0)(3.5,3)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=bottom,ticks=x,ticksize=0 4pt,xsubticks=5,xsubticksize=.5,labels=none](0,0)(-3,0)(3,3)
    \uput[d](-1,0){$\omega_{\text{nl}}$}
    \uput[d](1.5,0){$\omega_{\text{lin}}$}
    \uput[d](0,0){\tiny Frequency}
    \psline{<-}(0,2)(1,2)
    \psset{linecolor=gray}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](0,0)(0,3) 
    \psplot[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{-3}{1}{\f[x,-1]}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-.5}{3}{\f[x,1.5]}
    \pcline{<->}(*-1.5 {\f[x,-1]})(*-.5 {\f[x,-1]})\nbput{$\Gamma_{\text{nl}}$}
    \pcline{<->}(*1 {\f[x,1.5]})(*2 {\f[x,1.5]})\nbput{$\Gamma_{\text{lin}}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I have requested someone to draw a graph and he did this by the code I have shown. I am trying to run this in my Latex file but it is not working. What can I do? Moreover, Can you give any tips so i can draw  graph by using LaTeX code.

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Run with `latex->ps` or `latex->ps->pdf`.

Comment: What compiler and distribution are you using?

Comment: It didn't work for me either until I updated pstricks. After that, latex+dvips+ps2pdf worked fine. By the way, the screen shot seems to be of a different file than is quoted at the start of this answer.

Comment: @dan: Yes. The screenshot is different from the code posted at the start of this question. The code posted at the start of this question must be compiled with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence. But, the code I posted in my answer wraps `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence in a host input file (named `main.tex`) that must be compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex`.

Comment: @Marienplatz, then what else  I have to do to compile the latex code. I just copied the code to one of my latex file and then followed  `dvi->ps` `ps pdf` `dvi- pdf`

Comment: @ComplexGuy: Read my answer carefully. You might need to read it multiple times but one pass should be enough as my notes are usually well written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Important Notes

The following complete code wraps `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` compilation for the `diagram.tex` in a host input file (named as `main.tex`) and this `main.tex` must be compiled with

```
pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex
```

rather than

```
latex main.tex
dvips main.dvi
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None main.ps
```

Please read carefully my note above!

### Complete Code

```
% the name of this file is main.tex
% compile it with
% pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{diagram.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100,labelsep=3pt}

\def\f[#1,#2]{2*2^(-2.5*(#1-#2)^2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,0)(3.5,3)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=bottom,ticks=x,ticksize=0 4pt,xsubticks=5,xsubticksize=.5,labels=none](0,0)(-3,0)(3,3)
    \uput[d](-1,0){$\omega_{\text{nl}}$}
    \uput[d](1.5,0){$\omega_{\text{lin}}$}
    \uput[d](0,0){\tiny Frequency}
    \psline{<-}(0,2)(1,2)
    \psset{linecolor=gray}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](0,0)(0,3) 
    \psplot[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{-3}{1}{\f[x,-1]}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-.5}{3}{\f[x,1.5]}
    \pcline{<->}(*-1.5 {\f[x,-1]})(*-.5 {\f[x,-1]})\nbput{$\Gamma_{\text{nl}}$}
    \pcline{<->}(*1 {\f[x,1.5]})(*2 {\f[x,1.5]})\nbput{$\Gamma_{\text{lin}}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{latex diagram && dvips diagram && ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None diagram.ps}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\caption{Spectrum}\label{fig:diagram}
\includegraphics{diagram}
\end{figure}
Beauty without intelligence is a masterpiece painted on a toilet paper.
\end{document}
```

### More detailed explanation

In `main.tex` as a host input file, there is

```
\immediate\write18{latex diagram && dvips diagram && ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None diagram.ps}
```

which will compile `diagram.tex` with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` on the fly.

The `diagram.tex` is prepared on the fly via `filecontents` environment as follows.

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{diagram.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100,labelsep=3pt}

\def\f[#1,#2]{2*2^(-2.5*(#1-#2)^2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,0)(3.5,3)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=bottom,ticks=x,ticksize=0 4pt,xsubticks=5,xsubticksize=.5,labels=none](0,0)(-3,0)(3,3)
    \uput[d](-1,0){$\omega_{\text{nl}}$}
    \uput[d](1.5,0){$\omega_{\text{lin}}$}
    \uput[d](0,0){\tiny Frequency}
    \psline{<-}(0,2)(1,2)
    \psset{linecolor=gray}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](0,0)(0,3) 
    \psplot[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{-3}{1}{\f[x,-1]}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-.5}{3}{\f[x,1.5]}
    \pcline{<->}(*-1.5 {\f[x,-1]})(*-.5 {\f[x,-1]})\nbput{$\Gamma_{\text{nl}}$}
    \pcline{<->}(*1 {\f[x,1.5]})(*2 {\f[x,1.5]})\nbput{$\Gamma_{\text{lin}}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
```

And the last step is to consume the `diagram.pdf` as illustrated in the host body as follows.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\caption{Spectrum}\label{fig:diagram}
\includegraphics{diagram}
\end{figure}
Beauty without intelligence is a masterpiece painted on a toilet paper.
\end{document}
```

If you still don't understand, please drop comments as many as you want!

Comment: I'm using Winedt  how to run by this editor?

Comment: @ComplexGuy: I don't use Winedt. I use TeXnicCenter.

Comment: At first I run your code in the tex file called `main.tex`. After I have got the `diagram.tex` file. What next? will I run `DVI-PS`

Comment: @ComplexGuy: No. You don't need any other intervention as `diagram.pdf` will be generated on the fly via `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` that `main.tex` invokes silently behind the scene.

Comment: A question to you: how will I draw latex pic. I mean How will I predict the coordinates?

Comment: @ComplexGuy: Change `showgrid=true` and the grid will help you to determine the correct coordinates by educated trial and errors.

Comment: Why use the `filecontents` package? And why go through that method?

Comment: @azetina: To ease the newbie to do everything on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Running `latex->ps` yields the following `.ps` file:

[image]

Running `latex->ps->pdf` yields the same output but in `pdf` format. For example, in TeXnicCenter, you can find these options as seen in the diagram below:

[image]

Under WinEdt, the options are as follows:

1. Compile using LaTeX as shown.

   [image]
2. Run dvi->ps. Click on the icon [image]then
3. If pdf is necessary, click on [image]

or after compilation just click on [image]

Comment: I am using Kile and also Windt. How to run there?

Comment: I have attached the image,  what is showing the editor when I click  Latex

Comment: I have done the process,  dvi->ps then ps pdf  and then dvi pdf. But it showed >> i have edited in the question. please check.